# spring integration mqtt over udp or mqtt-sn

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

In IoT scenario a lot of standard force pushing packets to mqtt queues over UDP protocol. This scenario become more and more frequent day by day, and for this reason now we have a new kind of mqtt queues named [mqtt-sn](http://mqtt.org/new/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/MQTT-SN_spec_v1.2.pdf).

In spring-integration-mqtt I'm using a [paho client](https://eclipse.org/paho/), however this has a specific client implementation ready to use mqtt-sn (https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/c/embedded-sn/) and there is also an implementation of moquitto over mqtt-sn (https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto.rsmb).

There is any way to for spring-integration-mqtt over UDP protocol or there is an implementation which allow to use mqtt-sn over spring-integration?

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking here

Comment: @hardillb There is any way to for spring-integration-mqtt over UDP protocol or there is an implementation which allow to use mqtt-sn over spring-integration?

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) MQTT-SN broker bridge the messages to MQTT topics so just use the normal Spring/MQTT integration with a suitable broker.